# Question about qoutient groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

Write out an operation table for G/H for the given group G and subgroup H.
$G = U_{13}$  and $H = \{[1],[3],[9]\}$
I have got this far
$U_{13}=\{[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12]\}$

Now we will show that H is normal in G by showing that every left coset of H in G is equal to the right coset of H  in G
$
[1]H=H=H[1]$

$[2]H={[2],[6],[5] }=H[2]$

$[3]H={[3],[9],[1] }=H[3]$

$[4]H={[4],[12],[10] }=H[4]$

$[5]H={[5],[2],[6] }=H[5]$

$[6]H={[6],[5],[2] }=H[6]$

$[7]H={[7],[8],[11] }=H[7]$

$[8]H={[8],[11],[7] }=H[8]$

$[9]H={[9],[1],[3] }=H[9]$

$[10]H={[10],[4],[12] }=H[10]$

$[11]H={[11],[7],[8] }=H[11]$

$[12]H={[12],[10],[4] }=H[12]$

Now we have shown that H is normal in G

We know that
$|G/H|=|G|/|H| =12/3=4$

I know there is 4 elements in G/H but I don’t know which element?

Comment: Oh,dear! Please do use LaTeX to write mathematics in this site. You'll find directions in the FAQ section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$G/H$ consists of 4 cosets. In your notation these are $[1]H(=[3]H=[9]H)$, $[2]H(=[5]H=[6]H)$,  $[4]H(=\ldots)$, $[7]H(=\ldots)$.

The operation table for $G/H$ is built by the formula:  $[i]H\cdot [j]H = [ij]H$, e.g, $[4]H\cdot [7]H=[2]H$.

Comment: 4]H⋅[7]H=[1]H ?

Comment: No, $[4]H\cdot [7]H=[28]H=[2]H$ since $28\equiv 2 \mod 13$.